# Dividing into double doesn't work

Tags: java

I know this is a pretty stupid question but I can't seem to understand why it isn't working. The code in java looks something like this:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    double d=5/100;
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

}

However on the input instead of giving me 0.06 it gives me 0.05 it gives me 0.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: 5 is an integer. 100 is an integer. An integer divided by an integer gives an integer.

Comment: use (double) 5 / 100. And suggest you to use BigDecimal because double have trouble in calculating

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     double d=5.0/100.0;
    System.out.println(d);

  }
```

You must use double variables to Java do not round results.